# how to check if the key is being pressed continuously?

Tags: java

I tried this but it did not work.

I have to run an animation when the key is pressed.

### My code:

```
case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:

while(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED){

  estado = ANDA0;

  posX += 10;

}

estado = PARADO;

break;
```

Comment: Use the `KEY_RELEASED` event

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop will completely overwhelm the GUI event thread, preventing any actions from occurring, including animation actions and key reading events. Instead, I suggest that you:

- Use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) if this is Swing, not a KeyListener.
- Change use a Swing Timer as an animation loop, not a thread freezing `while (true)` loop.
- On key press (from the key bindings), change the state a state field
- On key release (again from bindings), revert the state of that same field
- Base what happens in your animation loop by the state of the state field changed above.

For example, please have a look at [this answer and example code of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31197660/522444)

Answer (score -1):

Something like this using the `KEY_RELEASED` event should do the trick:

```
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
    if (KeyEvent.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)
        bool = true;

    while(bool){

        estado = ANDA0;
        posX += 10;
        if (KeyEvent.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED)
        bool = false;

    }

    estado = PARADO;

  break;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does this work? In the Java i know of, busy-waiting for an event in the event handling thread would make the program freeze up.

Comment: @cHao I was presuming since he has used a `switch-case` that the key has already been pressed.

Comment: Yeah, but it has to be released before you get a `KEY_RELEASED` event. Which means you're waiting for a new event.

Comment: So `KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED` should evaluate to false till then, right? OH NVM, I get your point. I will edit my answer now

Comment: It'll evaluate to false _forever_, i'd think, because you don't return, which means you're tying up the event handling thread, which means that next event will never get processed. That's why i was asking -- something seems very weird about this.

Comment: You're still busy-waiting, though. And that event you already have is not going to change its type.