# Continuously pressed key

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have the following code snippet from my SWING game:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {         
             player.setX(player.getX() + speed);
             canvas.repaint();

        }
```

The code is working correctly, when I press the right arrow(`VK_RIGHT`),
the player moves RIGHT, if I press the left arrow it moves left.

The problem is when I hold the LEFT or RIGHT arrow, the player moves once and then it stops for some time and then it starts continuously moving the pressed direction.

I think it takes time for java to understand that the pressed button is HOLD. Any idea how I can make it move continuously instantly?

Comment: Please provide some code which reproduces the problem . With your code above, we can't give you the right answer.

Comment: Do you mean when you press the arrow "key", cause this gets asked quite a bit

Comment: Edited the description of my question

Comment: Looks like a similar question [link](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56017/java-best-implementation-keylistener-for-games). Probably the second answer can solve your problem.

Comment: That is caused by how your keyboard works - when you press down on a key, it causes a key event. After a short time lag with the key still held down, some (not all) keyboards will begin issuing a continuous stream of button press events until the button is released.

Comment: You need a flag to indicate which keys are pressed and background thread or timer which can repeatedly check the state of these flags and update the state of your objects, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423393/how-to-get-a-rectangle-to-stop-when-you-release-a-key-that-moves-it/28423725#28423725), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748547/java-swing-timer-only-works-once-then-keyevents-fire-in-rapid-succession-holdi/22749251#22749251), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328946/java-keylistener-stutters/16329029#16329029)

Comment: To emphasize this: This is not related to Java or Swing. Just press a key and hold it in any text editor: a<delay>aaaaaaaaaaaaaa.... Sometimes you can even set the delay and speed in the BIOS. Anyhow, the linked answers should help to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea how I can make it move continuously instantly?

- Animate the custom painted component by using a Swing timer to invoke repaint.
- Add a `KeyListener` to the component.
- Start moving on [`keyPressed(KeyEvent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyPressed-java.awt.event.KeyEvent-)
- Stop moving on [`keyReleased(KeyEvent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html#keyReleased-java.awt.event.KeyEvent-)